# binance_f get_income_history

Tags: python

Суть проблемы:
Хочется получить значения, которые есть в json, но не прописаны в модели:
вот модель:

class Income:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.symbol = ""
    self.incomeType = ""
    self.income = 0.0
    self.asset = ""
    self.time = 0

@staticmethod
def json_parse(json_data):
    result = Income()
    result.symbol = json_data.get_string("symbol")
    result.incomeType = json_data.get_string("incomeType")
    result.income = json_data.get_float("income")
    result.asset = json_data.get_string("asset")
    result.time = json_data.get_int("time")

    return result
```

эти 5 полей получаю, но когда приходят данные по комиссии, PNL нужно как-то высчитывать общую прибыль, для этого есть поля info, tradeId, tranId:

[{"symbol":"OCEANUSDT","incomeType":"COMMISSION","income":"-0.00160617","asset":"USDT","time":1623549663000,"info":"25986913","tranId":9145125986913,"tradeId":"25986913"},

я дописывал в модель строки, например:

class Income:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.symbol = ""
    self.incomeType = ""
    self.income = 0.0
    self.asset = ""
    self.time = 0
    **self.info = ""**

@staticmethod
def json_parse(json_data):
    result = Income()
    result.symbol = json_data.get_string("symbol")
    result.incomeType = json_data.get_string("incomeType")
    result.income = json_data.get_float("income")
    result.asset = json_data.get_string("asset")
    result.time = json_data.get_int("time")
    **result.info = json_data.get_int("info")**

    return result
```

Но толку нет. не понятно где питон хранит эти файлы, поиск ничего не дал

Надеюсь внятно объяснил суть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решился...
просто скопировал папку binance_f в папку Python-а
c:\Users\room1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages
все дополнения в модели заработали.. появилась возможность получать дополнительные данные. :)

вопрос: откуда Python брал данные для "binance_f" ранее???